# c# f#: WebApi: How do I do the equivalent of RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles with HttpRouteCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I would like to create a website with static html pages which call back to my WebApi. I am using nodejs, reactjs, and grunt to build my static pages. I would like my asp.net webapi project to give out the static pages. The static pages will then make calls back to my WebApi.

In Asp.net MVC, I have the following option:

```
((RouteCollection)routes).RouteExistingFiles = true
```

Is there an equivalent for for HttpRouteCollection which is used in asp.net WebApi?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It looks like they are automatically passed through. In another post, I've asked about how to default to index.html instead of the HomeController.